# Declaration emit for this file requires using private name 'HTMLMarker'. An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use code, that is not mine, so I can only adapt it for my purposes without logic change. Dev version of my project is working fine, but when I am trying to build it I get this annoying error: ***"Declaration emit for this file requires using private name 'HTMLMarker'. An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit."***

I have tried to adapt solutions from similar problems, described at Stackoverflow, but still cannot fix this problem. Here is my code, will be very appreciated for your help

```
/* @ts-ignore */
const createHTMLMarker = (google) => {
  class HTMLMarker extends google.maps.OverlayView {
    constructor({
      position,
      map,
      className,
      anchor = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      },
    }) {
      super();

      this.anchor = anchor;
      this.subscriptions = [];
      this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position);

      this.element = document.createElement('div');
      this.element.className = className;
      this.element.style.position = 'absolute';
      // Force the "white-space" of the element will avoid the
      // content to collapse when we move the map from center
      this.element.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';

      this.setMap(map);
    }

    onAdd() {
      if (this.getPanes()) {
        this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.element);
      }
    }

    draw() {
      if (this.getProjection()) {
        const position = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latLng);

        const offsetX = this.anchor.x + this.element.offsetWidth / 2;
        const offsetY = this.anchor.y + this.element.offsetHeight;

        this.element.style.left = `${Math.round(position.x - offsetX)}px`;
        this.element.style.top = `${Math.round(position.y - offsetY)}px`;

        // Markers to the south are in front of markers to the north
        // This is the default behaviour of Google Maps
        this.element.style.zIndex = parseInt(this.element.style.top, 10);
      }
    }

    onRemove() {
      if (this.element && this.element.parentNode) {
        this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element);

        this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => subscription.remove());

        delete this.element;

        this.subscriptions = [];
      }
    }

    addListener(eventName, listener) {
      const subscription = {
        remove: () => {
          this.element.removeEventListener(eventName, listener);

          this.subscriptions = this.subscriptions.filter(
            (_) => _ !== subscription
          );
        },
      };

      this.element.addEventListener(eventName, listener);

      this.subscriptions = this.subscriptions.concat(subscription);

      return subscription;
    }

    getPosition() {
      return this.latLng;
    }
  }

  return HTMLMarker;
};

export default createHTMLMarker;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be helpful if you could create a minimal reproducable sandbox of your project. Otherwise, we don't even know the library you use for Google Maps.

Does this code below help? Can you test it? Also, you were not using Typescript the correct way.

If you want to avoid TS checks for a specific file, you should use // @ts-nocheck at the top of your file

```
interface HTMLMarkerProps {
  map: string;
  position: {
    lng: number;
    lat: number;
  };
  anchor: {
    y: number;
    x: number;
  };
  className: string;
}

const getCustomHTMLMarker = (google : any) => class HTMLMarker extends google.maps.OverlayView {
  element? : HTMLDivElement;
  latLng : google.maps.LatLng;
  subscriptions: Array<{
    remove : () => void;
  }> = [];
  anchor : {
    x:number;
    y: number;
  } = {
    y: 0,
    x: 0,
  };
  constructor({
    position,
    map,
    className,
    anchor = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    },
  } : HTMLMarkerProps) {
    super();
    this.anchor = anchor;
    this.subscriptions = [];
    this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position);

    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.className = className;
    this.element.style.position = 'absolute';
    // Force the "white-space" of the element will avoid the
    // content to collapse when we move the map from center
    this.element.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';

    this.setMap(map);
  }

  onAdd() {
    if (this.getPanes()) {
      this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.element);
    }
  }

  draw() {
    if (this.getProjection() && this.element) {
      const position = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latLng);

      const offsetX = this.anchor.x + this.element.offsetWidth / 2;
      const offsetY = this.anchor.y + this.element.offsetHeight;

      this.element.style.left = `${Math.round(position.x - offsetX)}px`;
      this.element.style.top = `${Math.round(position.y - offsetY)}px`;

      // Markers to the south are in front of markers to the north
      // This is the default behaviour of Google Maps
      this.element.style.zIndex = `${parseInt(this.element.style.top, 10)}`;
    }
  }

  onRemove() {
    if (this.element && this.element.parentNode) {
      this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element);

      this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => subscription.remove());

      if (this.element) {
        delete this.element;
      }

      this.subscriptions = [];
    }
  }

  addListener(eventName : keyof HTMLElementEventMap, listener : (e : EventListener<HTMLDivElement>) => void) {
    if (!this.element) {
      return;
    }
    const subscription = {
      remove: () => {
        if (!this.element) {
          return;
        }
        this.element.removeEventListener(eventName, listener);

        this.subscriptions = this.subscriptions.filter(
          (_) => _ !== subscription
        );
      },
    };

    this.element.addEventListener(eventName, listener);

    this.subscriptions = this.subscriptions.concat(subscription);

    return subscription;
  }

  getPosition() {
    return this.latLng;
  }
}

export default getCustomHTMLMarker;
```

Also, why are you inheriting an HTMLMarker from an OverlayView? It doesn't make sense.

This sounds like an interesting question though, so you could update it with more details so I can help you with implementing the logic that you want to have in your app.